# Not using jQuery promise objects appropriately. Not sure why

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to use this in **coffeescript** :

```
  $(this).hide().each (index) ->
    $(this).delay(index * 100).fadeIn 1000, arguments.callee
  $(this).promise().done -> console.log 'hey trip'
```

**The same thing in au naturale JS**

```
  $(this).hide().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(index * 100).fadeIn(1000, arguments.callee)
  });
  $(this).promise().done(function() {console.log 'hey trip' });
```

And I'd like to execute the console log once the animation is complete. But this snippet here never delivers the console message ( in general ), let alone when the animation completes.

Anyone know how to use the promise objects appropriately?

**Second Failing Attempt** :

```
  promise = new $.Deferred ->
  promise.done -> console.log 'hey trip'

  promise.resolve( $(this).hide().each (index) ->
    $(this).delay(index * 100).fadeIn 3000, arguments.callee
  )
```

**Third failing Variation**

```
dfd = $.Deferred ->
dfd.done(
  $(this).hide().each (index) ->
    $(this).delay(index * 100).fadeIn(3000, arguments.callee)
).done -> console.log 'hey trip'
```

**Fourth failing variation**

```
$.when(
  $(this).hide().each (index) ->
    $(this).delay(index * 100).fadeIn(3000, arguments.callee)
).then -> console.log 'hey trip'
```

Comment: Yes it is terribly sorry. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is not related to event delegation...

Comment: could you maybe write it in real Javascript so the non-coffeescript readers can help?

Comment: Cool thanks Alnitak. Just wrote up a vanilla version of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `arguments.callee` parameter to `.fadeIn()`.

If you take that out, it works...   See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/9VQ48/

Comment: That works! How does arguments.callee cancel that out!? Wow thanks so much for that Alnitak. I owe you one.

Comment: @Trip I haven't figured that out yet.  Maybe you can't mix completion callbacks with promises?  In any event, `.callee` doesn't seem to make sense in that context?

Comment: I had never known. Thanks again :D